# How to allow username to be only in lowercase?

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I want to save username only in Lower case in database and for this I have tried the following two Regex which I found online but both allows to save letter in uppercase also. And also tell me which one is better out of both. Thanks.

```
 1:-   ^[a-z0-9_.]{4,29}$

 2:-   ^(?!.*\.\.)(?!.*\.$)[^\W][\w.]{4,29}$


helloWorld    // I don't want this to validate because "W" is in Upper case
hello_world 
hello.word13dm
World.Hello_23m    // I don't want this to validate because "W" and "H" is in Upper case
```

Comment: You mean you need to filter user's input, right? This has nothing to do with saving in database.

Comment: yes, but I am checking the existence of that username that it exist or not. Suppose, its ddd13 and another one types ddD13 then it saves both and I don't want that.

Comment: Solved: I have added this now with Regex and it don't allow to type in Upper case anymore. TextFormField(
                              inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp("[A-Z]"))]

Comment: Sure this can block upper case characters, but it will allow other special characters including emojis, you might not want that in usernames.

Comment: for that is this not enough? ^(?!.*\.\.)(?!.*\.$)[^\W][\w.]{4,29}$ or do I have to add something else in it to avoid special characters?

Comment: hey, @Crizant what about this? Now it allows only this:- [FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[a-z0-9_.]"))]

Comment: If you want to allow ".", make sure you escape it, e.g. "\.", since dot means any character in regex.

Answer (score 0):

On the first one, take out the '.' after '9_' (a dot means 'any character', which makes the rest of your class a bit redundant).

Comment: tried but still this allows with uppercase

Comment: Please note that: Dots are *not metacharacters* because they are within a
character class. Hence they will not match any character in the first regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> For lowercase letter: [a-z]
>
> For accepting numerals : [0-9]
>
> For accepting underscore : [_]

So the regex will be

> **^[a-z][a-z0-9_]*$**

EDIT :
More flexible regex :

> ^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-z0-9]+$

Comment: still this allows with uppercase and validates it

Comment: Try the updated . AFAIK , it is the working regex.

Comment: yes I checked it on this website https://www.regextester.com/104030. it still validates.

Comment: @GAGANSINGH It validates because you have turned on `case-insensitive` match. Please turn that off in flags and then try finding a match.

Comment: Solved: I have added this now with Regex and it don't allow to type in Upper case anymore. TextFormField( inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp("[A-Z]"))]

Answer (score 0):

Could you just check for uppercase? e.g. [A-Z]

```dart
void main() {
  RegExp exp = new RegExp(r"[A-Z]");
  List<String> testStrings = [
    "helloWorld",
    "hello_world",
    "hello.word13dm",
    "World.Hello_23m",
    "ddD13",
    "ddd13",
  ];
  for (var testString in testStrings) {
    var isValid = exp.allMatches(testString).isEmpty;
    print('$testString is Valid:$isValid');
  }
}
```

output:

```
helloWorld is Valid:false
hello_world is Valid:true
hello.word13dm is Valid:true
World.Hello_23m is Valid:false
ddD13 is Valid:false
ddd13 is Valid:true
```

Are there any other validation rules you have, except for no Uppercase?

Comment: thanks for your reply and yes the other rules, min 4 and  max 30 and only have "." , "numbers" , " _ ". and with only lower case.

Comment: Solved: I have added this now with Regex and it don't allow to type in Upper case anymore. TextFormField( inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp("[A-Z]"))]